# Why does HTTP::Message::decodable complain about "Can't use an undefined value as a HASH reference"?

Tags: perl, libwww-perl

I'm getting a `Can't use an undefined value as a HASH reference` error trying to call [HTTP::Message::decodable()](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/HTTP::Message) using Perl 5.10 / libwww installed on Debian Lenny OS using the aptitude package manager. I'm really stuck so would appreciate some help please.

Here's the error:

```
 Can't use an undefined value as a HASH reference at (eval 2) line 1.
at test.pl line 4
main::__ANON__('Can\'t use an undefined value as a HASH reference at 
`(eval 2)...') called at (eval 2) line 1
HTTP::Message::__ANON__() called at test.pl line 6
```

Here's the code:

```
use strict;
use HTTP::Request::Common;
use Carp;
$SIG{ __DIE__ } = sub { Carp::confess( @_ ) };

print HTTP::Message::decodable();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the [changelog](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/GAAS/libwww-perl-5.834/Changes), it looks like `HTTP::Message::decodable()` was added in version 5.814. Are you sure you are reading the right documentation for your version?

Try:

```
perl -MHTTP::Message -e 'warn $HTTP::Message::VERSION'
```

.. it should return 5.814 or more...

Comment: Thanks! I'm obviously not on the right version.

$ perl -MHTTP::Message -e 'warn $HTTP::Message::VERSION'
5.812 at -e line 1.

If I look in aptitude it says the libwww-perl package is on version 5.813-1 (I'm not sure why this is different to 5.812 given by the command above).  Looks like I need to upgrade

Answer (score 2):

Gavin was right - I had an old version of libwww-perl installed.  I was relying on using the latest version available on Debian Lenny (assuming this was fairly up to date).  Turns out the latest version available is 5.813 but I need 5.814 or more to use this function.  As there's no packaged version available via aptitude I installed the latest using CPAN instead:

```
$ perl -MCPAN -e shell
cpan[1]> upgrade HTTP::Message
```

All done!